# How to export saved model in the tutorial of "Recurrent Neural Networks for Drawing Classification"

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm going through tensorflow's tutorials, and got a problem on how to save the trained model.

In the tutorial, a recurrent neural network is defined and trained to do drawing classification. This is the corresponding code:

```
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(
      model_fn=model_fn,
      model_dir=output_dir,
      config=config,
      params=model_params)
  # Train the model.
  tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
      estimator=estimator,
      train_input_fn=get_input_fn(
          mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
          tfrecord_pattern=FLAGS.training_data,
          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size),
      train_steps=FLAGS.steps,
      eval_input_fn=get_input_fn(
          mode=tf.contrib.learn.ModeKeys.EVAL,
          tfrecord_pattern=FLAGS.eval_data,
          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size),
      min_eval_frequency=1000)
```

The [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/recurrent_quickdraw) doesn't give the code that shows how to export and save model. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial makes use of the `Estimator` API. Once the model is trained, you can save it by calling the `export_savedmodel()` method:

```
export_dir = './' # path to store the model
estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir, serving_input_fn)
```

The `serving_input_fn` is the serving-time equivalent of the `input_fn` during training time. This function should return a `ServingInputReceiver` object. The goal of this object is to receive a serving request, parse it, and send it to the model for inference. To do the parsing, you need to supply a `feature_spec` dictionary that tells the parsing function what features to expect. From the docs:

```
feature_spec = {'foo': tf.FixedLenFeature(...),
                'bar': tf.VarLenFeature(...)}
```

See the [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) for a detailed explanation on how to build it from scratch.

In most cases, you can use either the `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn` or the `build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn` utility function to build your `serving_input_fn`. The parsing receiver requires a feature specification as illustrated above, the raw receiver requires a mapping from strings to Tensors and will allow you to pass 'raw' (unserialized) input data as a request to the model. For example:

```
serving_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(
feature_spec,
default_batch_size=None)
```